# How to run multiple regressions using a for loop?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset with multiple cities, a response variable and one predictor. I'm trying to run a regression for each city. This not only returns me just one row of data but also returns the coefficient as NaN.

```
train_output = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['intercept','coefficient','r2'])

for cit in train.city.unique():

    y = train[train['city']==cit]['response']

    y = np.array(y.values.tolist())

    x = train[data['city']==cit]['predictor']

    x = np.array(x).reshape((len(x), 1))

    model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

    model_output = {'intercept':model.intercept_,'coefficient':model.coef_[0], 'r2': model.score(x,y)}

    df = pd.DataFrame(model_output, columns = ['intercept','coefficient','r2'], index = [cit])

    train_output.append(df)

    print(train_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit hard to tell without seeing the data.
However, the most common reason is a NaN or Inf in your input (either features or labels).
Do you get NaN for every iteration?

Comment: If I run the models for each city individually I get coefficients. But the loop returns NaN and only returns one row (and a different row each time) instead of the 100 rows I am expecting since I have 100 cities.

Comment: So probably something happens when you make the split. This is a new step that introduces the error. Did you check for NaN/Infs in the data when you split. 
try 
```
print(np.isnan(x).any())
print(np.isnan(y).any())
```

Comment: Both of those lines return False.